# don't execute a part of a SQL Script

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

When I Excute the script the compiler(?) ignore the Stored Procedure, don't show me any error

```
START TRANSACTION;
    DELIMITER $€
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GeneraTimeTable`(IN NumAutobus INT, IN NomeFermata VARCHAR(30),
    IN OraInizio TIME, IN OraFine TIME, IN Frequenza INT)
    BEGIN
        IF exists (select * from fermata where Nome=NomeFermata) 
        and exists (select * from autobus where Numero=NumAutobus) then
        INSERT INTO TIMETABLE (NrAutobus, NomeFermata, OrarioArrivo) VALUES (NumAutobus, NomeFermata, OraInizio);
        END IF
    END
    DELIMITER ;
COMMIT;
```

Can me help pls?

Comment: You reassign the delimiter but do not use new value anywhere. PS. Procedure creation does not need in a transaction.

Comment: yep but it doesn't create it

Comment: Just chande `END` to `END $€`. Also `END IF` to `END IF;`

Comment: THANKS YOU VERY MUCH!!!!